# XCode: Capturing swipe gesture and creating a moving object

Tags: iphone, xcode

Newbie in XCode & IPhone development.

I'm trying to create a game, where throwing an object (using a swipe gesture) will move the object to the direction requested and will continue with momentum until the border of the view.

Anyone has some code snippets (or links) I can look into for examples?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [cocos2D-iphone](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/) for animation and physics.